# Not able authenticate my Nodejs api using google cloud endpoint and Api key

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-endpoints, api-key, google-api-nodejs-client, app-engine-flexible

Please help .i am new to cloud endpoint and not able to authenticate my nodejs api using cloud endpoint and api key .

My nodejs api:https://iosapi-dot-ingka-rrm-ugc-dev.appspot.com is working perfectly .However it's not working after authenticate with cloud endpoint and Api key.

For fetching data(get), i am using routing in my api like :

https://iosapi-dot-ingka-rrm-ugc-dev.appspot.com/ugc/iosreviewratings/20200611 : 20200611 : is any date range i have to pass .
https://iosapi-dot-ingka-rrm-ugc-dev.appspot.com/ugc/iosreviewratings/20200611?Limit=2&Offset=1

after endpoint deployment ., whenever i am acessing my api with api key , i am getting error "    "message": "Method doesn't allow unregistered callers (callers without established identity). Please use API Key or other form of API consumer identity to call this API.",
"

My Cloud endpoint has been deployed successfully .The below are my openapi.yaml .(ingka-rrm-ugc-dev : is my project id)

### openapi.yaml

```
swagger: "2.0"
info:
  description: "A simple Google Cloud Endpoints API example."
  title: "Endpoints Example"
  version: "1.0.0"
host: "ingka-rrm-ugc-dev.appspot.com"
consumes:
- "application/json"
produces:
- "application/json"
schemes:
- "https"
paths:
  "/ugc/iosreviewratings/*":
    get:
      produces:
        - application/json
      operationId: "auth_info_google_jwt"
      parameters:
        - name: Limit
          in: query
          required: false
          type: string
          x-example: '200'
        - name: Offset
          in: query
          required: false
          type: string
          x-example: '2'
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Definition generated from Swagger Inspector
# This section requires all requests to any path to require an API key.
security:
- api_key: []
securityDefinitions:
  # This section configures basic authentication with an API key.
  api_key:
    type: "apiKey"
    name: "key"
    in: "query"
```

app.yaml
========--

```
runtime: nodejs
env: flex
service: iosapi

# This sample incurs costs to run on the App Engine flexible environment.
# The settings below are to reduce costs during testing and are not appropriate
# for production use. For more information, see:
# https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml

manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
resources:
  cpu: 1
  memory_gb: 0.5
  disk_size_gb: 10

# [START configuration]
endpoints_api_service:
  # The following values are to be replaced by information from the output of
  # 'gcloud endpoints services deploy openapi-appengine.yaml' command.
  name: ingka-rrm-ugc-dev.appspot.com
  rollout_strategy: managed
# [END configuration]
```

Please help me finding where is issue exactly and why api is not working with end point and api key

already enabled all service for for endpoint

```
gcloud services enable servicemanagement.googleapis.com
gcloud services enable servicecontrol.googleapis.com
gcloud services enable endpoints.googleapis.com

gcloud services enable ingka-rrm-ugc-dev.appspot.com
```

.

Comment: Are you sending api key in a query? Also check [this](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-parameters/#path-parameters) on path parameters.

Comment: You seem to have included your Google Cloud project ID in the question. If you would like to have it removed, please [edit] your question to submit a sanitized version, and then flag for moderator attention to have the revision history purged.